# Vim return to second last edited line

Tags: vim

In vim you can go back to the last edited line with '. , but is there a way to go back to the second-last edited line? Suppose I did some edits at line 100, then some edits at line 1, is there a quick way to return to line 100? I know a mark can be used but that requires forethought...

Comment: It would be nice if it worked similarly to "2p : 'n. returns to the n'th last edited line

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use the jumplist (`:help jumplist`).  Simply use `Ctrl-O` to go back (and `Ctrl-I` to go forward) in the list of the last places you either edited or jumped to (via `%`, `/`, `[[` etc: see `:help jumplist` for the full list).

To go back to the place you edited before last then assuming you've done no other jumps in the meantime, this would be `Ctrl-O` `Ctrl-O` or (I think) `2 Ctrl-O`.

Answer (score 9):

In addition to jumplist, vim has also a [changelist](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#changelist), which can be iterated over using `g;` (to older item) and `g,` (to newer item) motions.